# plot multiple columns on one axis python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm new to data analysis and am looking to plot a table that has multiple date columns as one of the axis. I have tried this:

```
years = [data['1996'],data['1997'],data['1998'],data['1999'],data['2000']]
data.plot(x=years,y=data['City'])
```

and

```
[data.plot(data[:,x],data2['City']) for x in range(3,5)]
plot.show()
```

where data is a pandas dataframer, neither are working. I feel like this is probably simple but can't seem to find the solution anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `City`, then transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = pd.DataFrame({'City':['a','b','c','d'],
                             '1996':[1,2,7,5],
                             '1997':[4,0,6,3],
                             '1998':[7,8,6,9],
                             '1999':[0,5,3,0]})

print (data)
   1996  1997  1998  1999 City
0     1     4     7     0    a
1     2     0     8     5    b
2     7     6     6     3    c
3     5     3     9     0    d

print (data.set_index('City').T)
City  a  b  c  d
1996  1  2  7  5
1997  4  0  6  3
1998  7  8  6  9
1999  0  5  3  0

data.set_index('City').T.plot()
plt.show()
```